# Removing multiple words from by positions

Tags: c++, string, c++17, variadic-templates

Define

```
template <int... Positions> void removeWords (std::string& str);
```

that will remove all the word (tokens) in the positions `Positions...` of `str`.  For example,

```
removeWords<1,3,8>(sentence);
```

will remove the 1st, 3rd, and 8th words from `sentence`.  How to do this, ideally using C++17 fold expressions?  Pre C++17, we would have to remove the word in position `First`, then then would have to decrease all the values of `Rest...` by 1 before applying it again, which is a total mess.

Comment: No, even in "pre C++17" that would be a rather inefficient and horrible way of doing that. The correct way of doing this requires just one pass over the string (removing all occurences of each specified word, all together, without having to "decrease" anything), and the fold expression version works the same exact way.

Comment: What does the `sentence` look like? Is it a single space separated or multiple space separated string? Can you provide more specific examples?

Comment: `std::set<int> positions_set{Positions...};` Now just walk over `str`, count words, and remove those whose positions are in `positions_set`